# Jquery find is not working on AJAX return data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
function openFaceBox(path) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        success: function( data ) {
            $.facebox( data ); // data returns html
                    var tableHeight = $(data).find('table').height();
                    console.log( tableHeight ); // Output : 0 (Zero)
        }               
    }); 
}
```

My AJAX return html is below :

```
<div id="holder-1">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="holder-2">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
</div>
<div id="holder-3">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here
            Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text
            Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some
            Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here
            Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text
            Here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can not figure out why `.find()` is not working. Basically I want to find table height.Any confusion please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter()`.

```
console.log($(data).filter('table'));
```

Presuming that `data` is a string of `HTML`, you can do this:

```
$(data).find('table');
```

That will return the `table` without adding the data to the `DOM`.

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas try adding  height="10" to table and then try..it always work..there is no height defined.

Comment: Actually I want to find the height of the table.Table data will be increased.So we can't set table height by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like

Register a `reveal.facebox` event handler

```
$(document).on('reveal.facebox', function(){
    var tableHeight = $('#facebox .content table').height();
    //Do whatever you want with the height
});

function openFaceBox(path) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        success: function( data ) {
            $.facebox( data ); // data returns html
                    var tableHeight = $(data).find('table').height();
                    console.log( tableHeight ); // Output : 0 (Zero)
        }               
    }); 
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aAubC/1/)

Note:
`$(data).find('table').height()` won't work since this element is not yet rendered to the dom, so there is no height/width for this element.
Once the facebox item is rendered facebox triggers a `revleal.facebox` event, and the facebox content is by default rendered to `#facebox .content` element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what $.facebox() is but you aren't going to be able to find the height of an element until it has loaded onto the DOM. This is kinda crazy but it should get you your height.

```
    $('body').append($('<div>',{class:'faceboxHolder'}).css('left':'5000px', 'position':'absolute').append(data));    

    var tableHeight = $('.faceboxHolder').find('table').height();

    $('.faceboxHolder').remove();
```