# jQuery find('#id') not working on Ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting some data through Ajax and I would like to get the content of a tag from its ID. I do not understand why it does not work:

```
$.get('/foo', function (data) {
    console.log('Found', data.match(/<.+\s+id\s*=\s*"display"[^>]+>.*?<\/div>/)[0]);
    console.log($(data).find('#display').length)
})
```

I get this:

```
Found <div id="display" data-title="Sandbox" data-display="plain"></div>
0
```

So I can confirm my tag is in the received data, but `$(data).find('#display')` does not find it.

Why?

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292605/jquery-find-is-not-working-on-ajax-return-data) one, but it does not explain why it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `find` looks at the *descendants* of the given node(s).

Notice how this will give a length of 1:

```
console.log($(data).filter('#display').length)
//                  ^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the node(s) in a parent, and *then* perform a `find`:

```
var wrapper = $("<div>").append(data);
console.log(wrapper.find("#display").length); // --> 1
```

Comment: Ok it works, but I don't understand what you mean by *descendants*. My `<div>` is a descendant of the html content hold by `data`.

Comment: With descendent, I mean that the #display element would be a child of a parent element that is also defined within that HTML. In your case, there is no such parent; the searched element is a top-level element. See also the alternative I added to my answer.